# Why does this.timeout have no effect when running an async test with mocha and pogo?

Tags: asynchronous, mocha.js, pogoscript

I am using [PogoScript](http://pogoscript.org) and mocha to test some code that makes an async call.

I need to increase the timeout but my code does not work. I have tried using `this.timeout(5000)` and `self.timeout(5000)` to no effect.

```
it 'runs some async code'
  self.timeout(5000)
  result = request!('some params')
  expect(result).to.be.true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal functions, use the `=>` operator before the block to have the caller (in this case mocha) define `self`:

```
it 'runs some async code' =>
  self.timeout(5000)
  result = request!('some params')
  expect(result).to.be.true
```

See [Pogoscript#Self](http://pogoscript.org/cheatsheet.html#self) for more information.